# How to build Delphi project in Linux through makefile?

Tags: delphi, jenkins

I am trying to port an application written in delphi from windows 32 bit to Linux 64 bit.
Using PAServer I can compile and building the application through Rad Studio.
But Here I am using Makefiles to compile and build in order to achieve automation using jenkins.
In windows the makefile is using few executables from Rad Studio like cgrc.exe , dcc32.exe, bcc32.exe and cl.exe to build the application.
So , what could be the suitable alternative or option for those executables to build my application in Linux through makefile (using jenkins).

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: We have a similar scenario. Our jenkinsfile calls a home-made script (happens to be a Python script) that calls the Delphi compiler executables for Windows or Linux. Just like you use dcc32.exe etc for Windows, you need to use the correct ones for Linux. In our case (using Delphi 10.4.2), the files needed are these: compllvm.dll, dcclinux64.exe, dcclinux64270.dll, ld-linux.exe. When you call dcclinux64.exe, you also need to (just like in the Windows case) tell it where to find library files (Delphi's libraries + the SDK for the Linux version you're targeting, e.g. ubuntu18.04.sdk).

Comment: Thank you for responding, your answer really helped. Do you have any idea about any alternatives/replacement for cgrc.exe?

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about that. (Are resources even used for non-Windows targets, aren't they a pure Windows thing? I know nothing about this. Our Linux project is a console/server application and has no resources.)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Will check that.